# Use install4j to create installer that just copies files to desktop

Tags: java, windows, installation, install4j

We are evaluating Install4J 6 to use to package a mixed Java / C++ application bundle. I have two directories that I simply copy files to on the client system. I have created two installation directories (rootDir & sys.userHome). Files intended for root are packaged up in what looks like an install4j installer (.install4J folder, with a bunch of files, and uninstall executable). The files in the user folder are as intended (just a bag of folders / files). I need to get install4J to just copy files into a number of folders on the client system, no packaging or altering the files. A zip would suffice but the customer wants a wrapper with localized EULA, instructions, etc. I have added actions to manipulate a couple of txt files (ini, xml) to update specific user / machine paths for our apps. And I need to kick off a couple of batch files to register some of the C++ content. The problem is those files are in the folder in the rootDir and I can't access them from within the .install4J folder.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanx

Comment: The "Install files" action installs all the files in the distribution tree. Do you have that action in your installer? If you do not want to install the .install4j folder with the runtime, deselect the "Install runtime" property of the action.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Ingo. I have experimented with the parameters under the install files action. If I uncheck the install runtime option, it adds the folder to the location in question but the only thing in it is the uninstall executable. I will play around with it a bit more and see if I can figure it out. Thanx again for the help.

Comment: I have removed the root in question from the distro tree and re-added it with the same results. I have removed the script used to pass the files from the repo to the installer and just added a link to the local files to remove the complexity in the installer. Is there a limitation in adding files to the client startup drive (wouldn't think so but I thought I would ask)? I am missing something really simple. I know it.

Comment: I don't understand the context of your questions, can you send your project file to support@ej-technologies.com and explain what you expect to happen?